# wshshell.popup not being displayed to other user when using task scheduler

Tags: vb.net, popup, scheduled-tasks

I've got a tricky thing to do here. 
I'm using task scheduler to auto-reboot all the computer during the weekend by calling a simple .bat file containing a shutdown command.

I wanted to give the user the possiblilty to cancel that reboot by displaying them a popup saying "Computer is about to restart, do you wish to continue ? Ok or Cancel". I have done that with VB using the popupbox method, it works perfectly.

Here is the problem i'm facing: The task is running under the System account and unless the task is set to run with the current logged on user, the popup box won't appear. I could change the account set in the task but I've got hundreds of users so impossible.

I've done some kind of a workaround, calling the VBS from Psexec... Works, but it's not perfect.

**Here is my Psexec command that calls the VB:**

```
Psexec -accepteula -s -i cmd /c C:\Windows\System32\Weekly_Reboot.vbs
```

**Here is my VB:**

```
Dim WshShell, BtnCode
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

BtnCode = WshShell.Popup("Computer is about to restart, do you wish to continue?", 30, "/!\ Weekly Restart /!\", 4 + 32)

Select Case BtnCode
    case 6      
    Dim objShell
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run "c:\Windows\System32\Weekly_Reboot.bat"

    case 7 
    WScript.Echo "No prob - the computer won't restart"

    case -1 
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run "c:\Windows\System32\Weekly_Reboot.bat"
End Select
```

**And here is the actual reboot command:**

```
Shutdown /f /r /c "This is the weekly reboot"
```

Any idea would be really awesome ! I really tried googling it, but no luck.

Comment: That is not VB.NET code. It looks more like VB6.

Comment: I have no idea, i just know it starts with VB :). I'm more a PowerShell guy, never done any VB*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is the problem i'm facing: The task is running under the System account and unless the task is set to run with the current logged on user, the popup box won't appear. I could change the account set in the task but I've got hundreds of users so impossible.

Change the task to run under the group called `Users`. It will make the task run for any logged in user.

I'm not certain if this is needed: but you might want to run it using the highest privileges.

Comment: Omg how could I not think about this -________-'

Comment: @AnthonyRegnier : If it works, please mark this as the accepted answer by pressing the check mark on the left of the post.

Comment: I'm running the task under "Domain Users" group and it pops up for every body so that's perfect. Answer has been marked as accepted. Thanks all

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!